# Erro de conexão utilizando namespace

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, namespace

Tenho um arquivo que é responsável pela conexão ao BD e é em PDO.

```
<?php

namespace clientes\model;

class conexaoPDO {

public static $instance;

private function __construct() {

}

public static function getIntance() {

    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {

        self::$instance = new \PDO('mysql::host=localhost;dbname=erpsuper', 'root', '', array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        self::$instance->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        self::$instance->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, \PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING);
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

}
```

Porém não estou conseguindo fazer o sistema conectar ao banco de dados, está aparecendo um erro que não estou conseguindo resolver.

```
Erro:
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to private 
clientes\model\conexaoPDO::__construct() from invalid context in 
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ERPSUPER\view\clientes\pesqcliente.php</b> on line 
<b>15</b><br />
```

Segue o código da rotina:

```
/*
 * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
 * Copyright: 2012 - John Becker, Beckersoft, Inc.
 * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine
 * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
*/

require_once("../../bootstrap.php");

use clientes\model\conexaoPDO;


$conn = new conexaoPDO();

class TableData {



public function get($table, $index_column, $columns) {
    // Paging
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['start'] ) && $_GET['length'] != '-1' ) {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['start'] ).", ".intval( 
    $_GET['length'] );
    }

    // Ordering
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['order'][0]['column'] ) ) {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";

        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($columns) ; $i++ ) {
            if ( $_GET[ 'columns'][$i]['orderable'] == "true" ) {
                $sortDir = (strcasecmp($_GET['order'][0]['dir'], 'ASC') == 
0) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
                if($_GET['order'][0]['column'] == $i){
                $sOrder .= "`".$columns[ intval( $_GET['order'][0]['column'] 
) ]."` ". $sortDir .", ";
                }
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );

        //if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" ) {
        //  $sOrder = "";
        //}
    }

    /* 
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does 
it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned 
about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['search']["value"]) ) {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";

        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($columns) ; $i++ ) {


            if ( isset($_GET['search']["value"])) {

                $sWhere .= "`".$columns[$i]."` LIKE :search OR ";


            }
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );

        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    // Individual column filtering
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($columns) ; $i++ ) {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == 
"true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' ) {
            if ( $sWhere == "" ) {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= "`".$columns[$i]."` LIKE :search".$i." ";
        }
    }

    // SQL queries get data to display
    $sQuery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".str_replace(" , ", " ", 
implode("`, `", $columns))."` FROM `".$table."` ".$sWhere." ".$sOrder." 
".$sLimit;
    $statement = conexaoPDO::getInstance()->prepare($sQuery);

    // Bind parameters
    if ( isset($_GET['search']['value'])) {
        $statement->bindValue(':search', '%'.$_GET['search']['value'].'%', 
PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($columns) ; $i++ ) {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == 
"true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' ) {
            $statement->bindValue(':search'.$i, 
'%'.$_GET['sSearch_'.$i].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
    }
    //var_dump($sQuery);
    $statement->execute();
    $rResult = $statement->fetchAll();

    $iFilteredTotal = current(conexaoPDO::getInstance()->query('SELECT 
FOUND_ROWS()')->fetch());

    // Get total number of rows in table
    $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(`".$index_column."`) FROM `".$table."`";
    $iTotal = current(conexaoPDO::getInstance()->query($sQuery)->fetch());

    // Output
    $output = array(
        "draw" => intval($_GET['draw']),
        "recordsTotal" => $iTotal,
        "recordsFiltered" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "data" => array()
    );

    // Return array of values
    foreach($rResult as $aRow) {
        $row = array();         
        for ( $i = 0; $i < count($columns); $i++ ) {
            if ( $columns[$i] == "version" ) {
                // Special output formatting for 'version' column
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $columns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ 
$columns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $columns[$i] != ' ' ) {
                $row[] = $aRow[ $columns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['data'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
}
}

header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
// Create instance of TableData class
$table_data = new TableData();

// Get the data
$table_data->get('clientes', 'id', array('id', 'nome', 'fantasia', 
'cnpj_cpf','municipio','nome_contato','email'));
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Se vc tem um singleton, não faz muito sentido tentar criar um objeto via construtor como nessa linha `$conn = new conexaoPDO();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente o erro está na linha que tenta criar um objeto via construtor pois ele está marcado como privado. Como está usando um singleton ... isso não faz muito sentido.

Linha que gera o erro:

```
$conn = new conexaoPDO();
```

Delhate importante da classe de conexão:

```
private function __construct() {}
```

Comment: Ola rray, Boa Tarde!
POderia me indicar como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: @SamuelVincenzo `$conn` não usada em nenhum lugar, logo pode remover essa linha `$conn = new conexaoPDO();`

Comment: è que eu esqueci de mudar as linhas, mas mesmo que eu retire esta linha aparece outro erro dizendo que não consegue conectar

Comment: @SamuelVincenzo qual é a mensagem de erro exata?

Comment: aparece este erro:
    <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method 
    clientes\model\conexaoPDO::getInstance() in 
    <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ERPSUPER\view\clientes\pesqcliente.php</b> 
     on line <b>89</b><br />

Comment: @SamuelVincenzo seu método foi definido como `getIntance()` e chamades deles estão como `conexaoPDO::getInstance()` veja que faltou um `s` na definição do nome.

Comment: Muito obrigado era isso mesmo! valew